# Quickly creating Scipy sparse matrix from adjacency list

Tags: graph, scipy, networkx, sparse-matrix, open3d

I am trying to create a networkx graph from an adjacency list. I am currently doing the following which is slow. I looked into the scipy.sparse matrix options and as far as I could tell none were in the same format as what I am working with. It is complicated by the fact that each item in adj can have a different length.

o3dmesh.adjacency list returns a list of sets.
The set adjacency_list[i] contains the indices of adjacent vertices of vertex i. There are no row, column indices, just an absolute index.

```
import open3d as o3d
import networkx as nx
import scipy

def adj_matrix(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    g= scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((n,n), int)
    for num, i in enumerate(adj):
        g[num, list(i)] = 1
    return g

o3dmesh = mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(path)
adj = o3dmesh.adjacency_list
adj = adj_matrix(adj)
graph = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(adj)
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide a [mcve], I took an imperfect guess at recreating your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `networkx` or your adj list.  But from the code I guess it's a list or array of integers in the (0,n) range.

Here's the most common way of constructing a matrix from such an array:

```
In [28]: from scipy import sparse                                                              
In [29]: adj = np.random.randint(0,10,size=10)                                                 
In [30]: adj                                                                                   
Out[30]: array([4, 7, 9, 7, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 8])
In [31]: data = np.ones_like(adj)                                                              
In [32]: rows = np.arange(10)                                                                  
In [33]: col = adj                                                                             
In [34]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows, col)), shape=(10,10))                              
In [35]: M                                                                                     
Out[35]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [36]: M.A                                                                                   
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Though to use your function, I have turn that into a 2d array:

```
In [39]: M1 = adj_matrix(adj[:,None])                                                          
In [40]: M1                                                                                    
Out[40]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [41]: M1.A                                                                                  
Out[41]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

If `adj` is a list (or object array) of lists, the `coo` construct will be a bit more complicated. Details will depend on what your initial `adj` looks like.  The goal is to have one entry in each of the 3 `coo` input arrays for each nonzero element of the matrix.

## list of sets

OK, let's create a list of sets:

```
def foo():
    n = np.random.randint(0,10)
    return np.random.randint(0,10,(n,))

In [34]: alist = [set(foo()) for _ in range(10)]                                             
In [35]: alist                                                                               
Out[35]: 
[{0, 1, 3, 6, 9},
 {1, 9},
 {0, 2, 5},
 {0, 1, 2, 5, 8},
 {1, 4, 5, 8},
 {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
 {0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9},
 {0, 1, 4, 7},
 {0, 4, 7, 8},
 {1, 5, 7, 8, 9}]
```

**You** should have provided such a test case or function.  I did ask for a [mcve].

Your function:

```
def adj_matrix(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    g= sparse.dok_matrix((n,n), int)
    for num, i in enumerate(adj):
        g[num, list(i)] = 1
    return g
```

An adaptation of my previous code to handle the new adj input:

```
def my_adj(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    row, col, data = [],[],[]
    for num, i in enumerate(adj):
        c = list(i)
        m = len(c)
        col.append(c)
        data.append([1]*m)
        row.append([num]*m)
    data = np.hstack(data)
    row = np.hstack(row)
    col = np.hstack(col)    
    return sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(n,n))
```

Compare the results:

```
In [36]: adj_matrix(alist)                                                                   
Out[36]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 45 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [37]: _.A                                                                                 
Out[37]: 
array([[1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])
In [38]: my_adj(alist)                                                                       
Out[38]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 45 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [39]: _.A                                                                                 
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

timings:

```
In [44]: timeit adj_matrix(alist).tocoo()                                                    
2.09 ms ± 76.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [45]: timeit my_adj(alist)                                                                
259 µs ± 203 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: The problem is that my function is taking too long. It is already successfully turning into a sparse array. Format is list of sets where each set is of variable size.

Comment: extended my answer to handle a list of sets.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.